# Command 'bg' and '&' don't work on Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, process, system-administration

I'm running Linux:

```
Linux davide 5.7.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.6-1kali2 (2020-07-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try to run some process in the background they appear on the terminal and I can see all the STDOUT. I tried both with the command "'Ctrl+z'+bg" and '&' after the expression.

Example: `Ping -c 10 127.0.0.1 &`

It seems that the process is running in the background (in fact I receive the PID like if it is working) but then I see all the output in the terminal.
I can also run other commands like here:

```
$ ping -c 10 127.0.0.1 &
[1] 2079
$ PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56 (84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
ls
 Desktop   Documents   Downloads   Music   Pictures   Public   Templates   Videos
$ 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9215ms
Rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.041/0.052/0.059/0.004 ms
[1]+  Done    ping -c 10 127.0.0.1
```

I don't know if is a bug of the new release or a misconfiguration, but I could't find any topic about this. Can Somebody help with this?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. Did you want to the outputs to be ignored? `<command> &> /dev/null &`

Comment: Why is this default? A process in the background shouldnt dislpay anything. I have already found that redirecting the output to a file ( command > file.txt) works. I am a newbie, I just suppose that. Anyway thanks for the immediate help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is used to make the command run the background but it does not make its output to hide.

If you want to redirect the output to a file use `>`, which is used to redirect the output.

E.g:

> ping [www.wikipedia.com](http://www.wikipedia.com) > output.txt &

Also, you can redirect the output to `/dev/null` if you don't want to store it although it would not be relevant here.

Regarding `Ctrl + z`: It is used to put a command to suspend mode not run in background. For more information see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Ok thanks, that is what was missing... I didnt understand how those commands works. I thought that background==no-output. Thanks you very much

Comment: this might help: https://www.guru99.com/linux-redirection.html